# How to print receipt with USB printer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, kiosk

I am developing a KIOSK app which is supposed to dispense receipt. The printer I'll be using is [TL80](http://www.custom.biz/self-service-industrial/solutions-for-self-service-kiosks/kiosk-printers/tl80)

It has no drivers. No SDK for .NET , No code examples etc. 
I did a google search but could not find anything with C#.

Comment: You should contact support department of this company

Comment: The page you linked mentions *"Auto-installing driver for WinXP/Vista/7(+64bit support)"* As for printing in .Net: Unless you are using ESC/POS this shouldn't be device-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Your supplier should have supplied a copy of [the Command Reference manual](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?action=dlattach;topic=405348.0;attach=169850) (third party link, probably not ideal) for that printer, which describes the exact commands you can send it over RS232.

As far as I know, the TL80 supports either TG2460 or ESC/POS emulation. There are many third-party ESC/POS libraries available (and Microsoft's own `PosPrinter` API is possibly compatible if you're connecting over network or Bluetooth).